# HashMap in Unary Functional Interface with Lambda in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, hashmap, unary-function

I'm studying for Java 8 Lambda and Unary Functional Interface. I have a practice assignment about "Function" class using `HashMap`, which the following steps to do:

1. Create a variable of type `Function<Set, Map>` that receives a `Set` and creates a `HashMap` using lambda expressions
2. Put words in the map, using as key the uppercase first letter of that word
3. Execute lambda expression and view the result

I trying in the following way, but it doesn't work. I think that the problem is in the lambda expression, but I want to understand how I have to do (for simplicity I put the same word as key). In this way, the result is "null".

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class FunctionTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();
        hs.add("ciao");
        hs.add("hello");
        hs.add("hallo");
        hs.add("bonjour");

        Function<Set, Map> setToMap = s2 -> (Map) new HashMap().put(s2,s2);

        System.out.println(setToMap.apply(hs));
   }
}
```

For the above example, the expected result should be `{B=bonjour, C=ciao, H=hello}`.

Comment: So what exactly is the result you want? A `Map` from `Character` to `String`?

Comment: I want to use the Unary function "Function" in order to pick a Set and create an HashMap in which are stored words of the Set

Comment: @Aaron I wrote "(for semplicity I put the same word as key)". The result is simply "null"

Comment: is that the result expectted : {B=bonjour, C=ciao, H=hello} ?, first leter as key, word as value

Comment: @azro yes, exactly!

Comment: @azro no no, the expected is:   {B=bonjour, C=ciao, H=hello}

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding something from your assignment, because this is not how typically these things work. What you probably want is a `Function<String, Character>` and then you would stream all the entries of the set to convert it to a `Map`

Comment: @AlfonsoSilvestri yeah, I guess I had missed the latest edit. [I reproduce your null](https://ideone.com/eyT2bn) after having removed the `setToList.apply(hs)` call which I guess correspond to a previous test.

Comment: @jbx yes..but it is my first approach with these things, thus I want to understand how it works

Comment: A general tip: don't use raw types, it makes it harder to keep track of what is going on.

Comment: you probably also need `Map<Character, List<String>>` as you have two `hello` and `hallo` (both start with h)

Comment: @Aaron sorry, setToList is other stuff, don't care about it

Comment: The problem is that your `Function<Set,Map>` creates a `HashMap` with a single entry that has the set both as key and value (s2 is the set, not one of its entries). Following what jbx said, you need instead a `Function<String, Map.Entry<String,String>>` which creates a map entry from a set entry, then stream the Set to map it to a Map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this means that you have to add all the `words` of the `Set` in the `Map` following 2 rules

- the key is the first letter in uppercase
- the value is the word

---

```
Function<Set<String>, Map<Character, String>> setToMap = aSet -> {
    Map<Character, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String s : aSet ) {
        map.put(s.toUpperCase().charAt(0), s);
    }
    return map;
};
// or using Streams :
Function<Set<String>, Map<Character, String>> setToMap = aSet  -> 
      aSet.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.toUpperCase().charAt(0), 
                                             Function.identity(),
                                             (oldK, newK) -> oldK)); // merging function in cas of duplicate key
```

---

Tip: don't use raw types, but specify them as much as possible:

- `Function<Set,Map>` becomes `Function<Set<String>, Map<Character, String>>`

Comment: @Eugene That's ok, given the OP's expected result

Comment: @pkpnd I dont think the OP has a very clear view of the expected result

Comment: @Eugene Fair enough I guess.

Comment: Ok thank you! This is how I expected that! But according to what @Eugene says, there are two words that starts with "h"..the key must be unique, thus this means that I cannot have both words beginning with "h" using this  operation, right?

Comment: @AlfonsoSilvestri if it satisfies you can accept it, or give details to improve

Comment: @AlfonsoSilvestri in that case (if you want a `List` as value), you should use `Collectors.groupingBy( s-> s.toUpperCase().charAt(0))`

Comment: @Eugene ok, thank you! Your answer satisfy my question and solve my problem

Comment: @AlfonsoSilvestri OK. This does not work for your case with `Hello` and `Hallo` though.

Comment: @jbx yes I know. But track says only this, and without use of stream

Answer (score 2):

I bet that you misunderstood your problem a bit.

You probably want a function that gets the key from the value of each item you have in the set. So:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add("ciao");
set.add("hello");
set.add("bonjour");

Function<String, Character> keyExtractor = s -> Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0));

Map<Character, String> map = set.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(keyExtractor, Function.identity()));
```

This assumes you only have one word for each letter.

If you want to have more than one entry for each first letter then you can do:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add("ciao");
set.add("hello");
set.add("hallo");
set.add("bonjour");

Function<String, Character> keyExtractor = s -> Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0));

Map<Character, List<String>> map = set.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(keyExtractor));
```

If you wanted to do it without streams, it will be more complicated but possible:

```
Function<Set<String>, Map<Character, List<String>>> setConverter = set -> {
      Map<Character, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

      for (String s : set) {
        Character key = Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0));
        map.compute(key, (k, v) -> {
          if (v == null) {
            List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
            newList.add(s);
            return newList;
          } else {
            v.add(s);
            return v;
          }
        });
      }

      return map;
    };
```

Comment: This answer is also great, but I don't have to use streams actually. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();
    hs.add("ciao");
    hs.add("hello");
    hs.add("hallo");
    hs.add("bonjour");
    //System.out.println(setToList.apply(hs));

    Function<Set<String>, Map<String,String>> setToMap = s2 -> {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        for ( String o : s2)
        {
            map.put(o.toUpperCase(), o);
        }
            return map;
        };

    System.out.println(setToMap.apply(hs));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class FunctionTest {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
           HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();
           hs.add("ciao");
           hs.add("hello");
           hs.add("hallo");
           hs.add("bonjour");

           Function<Set<String>,Map> function=set ->{

              Map<String,String> mapSet=new HashMap<>();

              set.forEach(valueOfSet->mapSet.put(valueOfSet.substring(0,1).toUpperCase(),valueOfSet));'

              return mapSet;
        };
        System.out.println(function.apply(hs));
   }
}
```

Without Using Function you can do it as below:

```
Map<String,String> mapSet=new HashMap<>();
hs.forEach(value->mapSet.put(value.substring(0,1),value));
System.out.println(mapSet);
```